# How do I make an iMovie 11 project into a DVD without iDVD?

Tags: idvd, imovie

I'd like to do a dry run of how a slideshow in imovie-11 is doing to come out when I run it for real, if I decide that 'for real' means 'playing a DVD on a DVD Player with a projector.'

Other answers here have dissed idvd as an obsolete item, and I am noting that my 9:24 movie has idvd sitting there spinning a cursor for a very, very, long time. So I have other choices?

Comment: iMovie hasn't  been updated for a while, but it isn't obsolete if you want to make a DVD. Just wait out the beachballs (that works OMM).

Comment: Did you mean 'idvd ...' rather than 'imovie ...'?

Comment: Also, idvd starts by bringing up a screen in which I to select from a menu of irrelevancies. What do I pick?

Comment: @Nathan iPhoto, iMovie, and GarageBand were all updated in the last interation of iLife, iDvd and iWeb were not.

Comment: Yup, I meant that iDVD hadn't been updated. My bad.

Comment: @bmargulies: Which irrelevanceis might these be?

Comment: @Nat e.g. 'the instant option' which goes directly from camera to DVD. It should just be engaging with what's arriving from iMovie, and instead it's discussing with me whether i want to do something else entirely.

Comment: You're using the Share-> Send to iDVD option?

Comment: @Nat yes, but I didn't pre-launch iDVD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has just issued an update to iDVD to make it more stable, and help with importing from iPhoto. With any luck, it will solve this. Get it through Software Update, or from [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1353).

Answer (score 2):

Even though iDvd is a bit of a mothballed application, you might be able to get around your hassles with one of these workarounds (iDVD was always a little buggy transferring from iMovie to iDVD anyway).

- Try exporting your slideshow from iMovie using the default settings of Share -> 'Export Movie using Quicktime', then import that .mov or .dv file into DVD by dragging and dropping it into iDVD. If you're confident export the movie using 'Export Movie using Quicktime' with the following settings:

  > For best results, in the QuickTime export settings, choose NTSC-DV with a frame rate of 29.97 or PAL-DV with a frame rate of 25. Choose No Compression for audio and set the rate to 48 kHz  ([here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=122593))
- If you still don't have any luck, use the 'Save as Disk Image' option in iDVD, and then use Disk Utility to burn that image to a DVD (drag the disk image into Disk Utility, click on it and choose burn). Leave a comment if you'd like more detailed instructions on how to do this.
- If that doesn't work use iDVD's built in Slideshow function. The options are pretty sparse compared to today's iPhoto / iMovie's effects, but it might do the trick for you.
- [Toast](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html), [Xilisoft](http://www.xilisoft.com/dvd-creator-mac.html) and [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html) can also create DVD video discs.