# How to make DVD from iMovie

Tags: macos, imovie, dvd

Apple has decided to exclude iDVD from Lion, and I haven't found an easy way to make a DVD that can be played on my DVD player created in iMovie.

I found this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6527/how-do-i-make-an-imovie-11-project-into-a-dvd-without-idvd)

However, there is no clear answer there.
I dont have iDVD, and I cannot get it, but I still want to be able to create a DVD.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Weird; iDVD isn't in the App Store either.

Comment: It's been discontinued

Answer (score 4):

You can export your movie to a format of your wishes (.avi, .dv, ...) and then you can burn this on a disk with a suitable software suite ([Roxio Toast](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/default.html) or with the built in software of Lion/Mac OS)

**EDIT**: for free, software, I would recommend you use [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html)

Comment: Are you sure you are able to burn standard DVDs (usuable in a plain DVD player) without additional software? Please add some explanation.

Comment: Yes because that is the main problem for me. I have exported it to m4v, but I have not found any free software that can burn to standard DVD format for my dvd player. I have found commercial software though, but want free

Comment: Sure there is :-) Try 'Burn' (see my edit). Free and makes playable DVDs for you DVD player.

Comment: An actual DVD (not just some movie burned onto a DVD-R that can be played by some DVD players) is in a VIDEO_TS folder, encoded MPEG2.  Does "burn" in Lion do that?  Aren't you supposed to pay for an MPEG2 license to do that anyway?

Answer (score 1):

See if you can find a friend who actually bought the boxed set of iLife before Apple outmoded iDVD. If so, have them copy iDVD.app out of their applications folder and give it to you.

Comment: That is most definitely not permitted by the [End User License Agreement](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/iLife11.pdf) that such a friend would have had to agree to.

Comment: If they make a copy and keep using theirs, it's not allowed.  If they don't need it any more, it should be fine to *give* it to you (and delete their own copy).

Answer (score 0):

DVD-Creator is well reviewed, similar to iDVD and $39.99 on the Mac App Store.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dvd-creator/id428417852?mt=12

I have no connection with this app or the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Correction: iMovie '11 does NOT have a direct option to burn to DVD

You will either have to share via web or download a dvd encoding burning program.

Disk utility is another way to burn dvd's, unfortunately it won't be in a format that is playable on a dvd player.  It would end up burning as a Data DVD

-Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

In iMovie '11 go to the Share menu and select Burn to DVD.