# How can I turn a iMovie video into a "proper" DVD?

Tags: video, imovie, dvd

iMovie only has the option to export the film as a .mp4 file. I know that MAGIX can create title cards and menus etc. Is it possible to do the same with Apple Software?

I also haven't found any option to burn the movie file on a DVD other than [burn](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/31982/238729), but that was last updated in 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html) should still work.
There's also the old Apple iDVD & though I haven't tested burning anything with it, it still appears to work on Mojave.
It appears to also still be available from Apple - https://support.apple.com/downloads/iDVD

Macworld did an article on it a few years ago & came to similar conclusions - [How to burn movies to disc in an iDVD-less world](https://www.macworld.com/article/2459440/how-to-burn-movies-to-disc-in-an-idvd-less-world.html)

They also mentioned [Roxio Toast](https://www.roxio.com/en/products/toast/) (now up to v17) as a paid alternative

<sup>BTW, I can't properly test any of this, as I have no DVD drive except in the Mac. I have to rip bought DVDs to even be able to watch them on the TV ;)</sup>

Comment: iDVD available from the link in your answer is actually an upgrade installer which e.g. iDVD 7.1.2 the file within the iDVD7.1.2Update.dmg file errors out with "**Alert** iDVD 7.0.4 or later is required to install this update." however, it appears to install properly using Pacifist to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Given the posting date the following may not be the optimal solution – now. But as a general answer to question I recommend to look into the following alternatives:

Apple iDVD is at 7.1.2 from  12 July 2011 and costs quite a stipend for simple yet limited functionality.

For video editing: [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/), free, cross platform,  version 2.4.3, released 22 September 2018

For creating DVDs:

[DVDStyler](https://www.dvdstyler.org/de/herunterladen), free cross platform, last updated Aug 28, 2018

[OpenDVDproducer](https://github.com/jonata/opendvdproducer/releases), free, cross platform, version 16.11  released on Nov 16, 2016

Comment: That I‘ve asked a day before Christmas doesn’t mean anything - just that I finally got around finishing that project. Thanks for the alternatives, I‘ll look into them!